# How to change env configuration in Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, email, environment-variables, laravel-8, laravel-7

I want to change env configuration from Controller, but this didnt work.

**Controller**

```
    config(['MAIL_HOST' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net']);
    config(['MAIL_PORT' => '25']);
    config(['MAIL_USERNAME' => 'apikey']);
    config(['MAIL_PASSWORD' => 'SG..']);
    
        Mail::send(
            'vendor.maileclipse.templates.news',
            ["content" => $content],
            function ($message) use ($email) {
                $message->to($email)->subject('Email');
            }
        );
    }
```

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=
MAIL_PORT=
MAIL_USERNAME=
MAIL_PASSWORD=
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=xy@xy.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="Test"
```

**mail.php**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set like  below

```
   config([

            'mail.mailers.smtp.host' => '',
            'mail.mailers.smtp.port' => ,
            'mail.mailers.smtp.encryption' => '',
            'mail.mailers.smtp.username' => '',
            'mail.mailers.smtp.password' => '',
            'mail.from.address' => ''

        ]
    );
```

This will override from mail.php

```
 'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],
```

Note:As infromed by @ceejayoz in comment .Remembe tt should be noted that this will only change it for that request. It will not change it for other requests, and will not update the .env file. –

**Updated**

```
 config([
    
                'mail.host' => '',
                'mail.port' => ,
                'mail.encryption' => '',
                'mail.username' => '',
                'mail.password' => '',
                'mail.from.address' => ''
    
            ]
        );
```

Comment: It should be noted that this will only change it for **that request**. It will not change it for other requests, and will not update the `.env` file.

Comment: @ceejayoz.ys definelty.thanks for reminding

Comment: Its not working. My mail.php doesnt look like this. I edited my post.

Comment: @xMrViktorx The same technique can be used, you just have to name the config keys appropriately. From your screenshot, you'd use stuff like `mail.driver` and `mail.host`.

Comment: first check default configuration works.if it works then  check configured values are correct .if still not working then check for errors what it say

Answer (score 1):

Use `config` file keys instead of `.env` variables, in your case `config/mail.php`

```
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.host' => 'smtp.sendgrid.net']);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.port' => '25']);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.username' => 'apikey']);
config(['mail.mailers.smtp.password' => 'SG...']);

    Mail::send(
        'vendor.maileclipse.templates.news',
        ["content" => $content],
        function ($message) use ($email) {
            $message->to($email)->subject('Email');
        }
    );
}
```